# Windows Phone 7 - Displaying Touch Points for Screen-Cast

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there an easy way to display the touch points on the emulator? I wish to record a screen cast and instead of capturing the mouse, I would like to display the touch points - which I think will lead to better screen-cast?

If there is no setting that allows one to display the touch-points, is there some simple code/library that I can add to my app, that will allow me to display the touch points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything built in that can do this.

You could have a look at Laurent Bugnion's sample here which does basically what you're looking for and see if you can apply it to your needs.

[MultiTouch Behavior for Windows Phone 7: Videos #wp7dev](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/07/04/multitouch-behavior-for-windows-phone-7-videos-wp7dev.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+galasoft+%28Laurent+Bugnion+%28GalaSoft%29%29&utm_content=Twitter)

[MultiTouch Behavior: Update for Windows Phone 7 tools beta](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/07/12/multitouch-behavior-update-for-windows-phone-7-tools-beta.aspx)